# Restoring Windows service programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am writing a Windows service. After installation, the Windows service copies the application and keeps it in back up at a certain path.

Now I want to reinstall later version of the Windows service.

I uninstall an older version of Windows service, then I try to install the latest version. But if it fails it needs to restore the old service from the concerned path.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525332/restoring-old-application-during-installation-in-vs-net

Comment: But MSI doesnot do that.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an installer you need to specify the following :

- Set Remove Previous Installation as True
- Set Detect new version as True
- Your C# program's version must increase with every deployment
  You should change the version of your installer to one higher version and it will ask you to change product code, select YES.

If you do all the above steps the installer will automaticaly unstall the previous version and it will try to install the new version.

**UPDATE:**

To add the custom actions, follow these steps:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click ServiceSetup, point to View, and then click Custom Actions.
2. Right-click Custom Actions, and then click Add Custom Action.
3. Click Application Folder, and then click OK.
4. Click Primary output from **yourservice(Active)**, and then click OK. Notice that Primary output appears under Install, Commit, Rollback and Uninstall.

Create two versions of installers with all above steps. when you run secound time previous version will removed from the system and installer will install latest vesrion and also if error occured rollback will be handled by the installer.

Comment: Thanks.
I have done the above steps.Say what if the installation fails , I need to restore the old version.This being installation of Windows Service we need to uninstall the old version to install the new version.How is it possible?

Comment: The MSI also works differently for installing non service exe and service exe.The MSI automatically uninstall the previous version in a non service exe.

Comment: Will the installer also stop the service properly?

Comment: Before Uninstalling the old version,The service is stopped manually. Also only after proper uninstallation of old version, a new version is started to install.

Comment: Are you using Custom Action for roleback?

Comment: No ..Can we  go a little deeper.Say what actions to be done on RollBack.

Comment: You mean to say programmitically  I need to install Old Service on RollBack Event?